# Could somebody please explain NetworkStream.BeginRead()?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, networkstream

I'm having such a hard time trying to figure out exactly how to use this method.  More specifically, I'm finding it difficult to understand what I'm supposed to be doing with the "callback" and "state" arguments.  I've read the documentation over and over along with some obscure, distantly related threads in forums about it. 
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You pass the networkstream itself as the "state" parameter.

In the callback, you extract the network stream back from the "ar" parameter and then call EndRead():

```
Dim stream As NetworkStream = CType(ar.AsyncState, NetworkStream)
Dim bytesRead As Integer = stream.EndRead(ar)
```

Your data will be in the buffer you specified back in the BeginRead() call.  Use "bytesRead" to know how much of the buffer has data in it.